# Postgresql Regular Espression to match only UPPERCASE word

Tags: regex, string, postgresql

I need to match and replace all UPPERCASE word in a Postgres string field like

```
'SANNAZZARO DE' BURGONDI Italia, 46 (Direzione Sud)'
'S.MARGHERITA STAFFORA Vallechiara (Bivio Montemartino)'
'GARLASCO Cavour/Oriani'
'GAMBOLO' Umberto I, 312'
```

This regular expression:

```
\b[A-Z'\''.]{2,}\b
```

tested with https://regex101.com/ works (except for 'GAMBOLO' Umberto I, 312').

But It doesn't work in postgres:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('GARLASCO Cavour/Oriani', '\b[A-Z\''.]{2,}\b','g');
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('GARLASCO Cavour/Oriani',' \b[A-Z\''.]{2,}\b','','g')
```

match nothing.

Also I try without  \''.

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('GARLASCO Cavour/Oriani', '\b[A-Z]{2,}\b','g');
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('GARLASCO Cavour/Oriani',' \b[A-Z]{2,}\b','','g')
```

Comment: Try `[A-Z\.]{2,}`, I don't see the need for `\b` in here which I doubt works with pg's primitive regex engine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i want match uppercase word(s) and delete